# Knockout.js 3.4.1 throws multiple bindings error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm working on a rather large project where I use KnockoutJS (large as in it would be impossible to post all related code here), and today I upgraded from Knockout 3.4.0 to 3.4.1. After doing this, I am suddenly getting a multiple bindings-error on every pageload ("You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element").

I have been using Knockout for a while, and I am very confident that I am in no way applying bindings multiple times to the same element. I only call applybindings once, and I have confirmed that this statement also only ever runs once by debugging that code (and also searching for any other instances of this function).

After debugging this problem for I while, I decided to downgrade again, to Knockout 3.4.0. And as it turns out, the error is only showing up on the latest build, version 3.4.1.

Anyone else noticed this behaviour? What did they change to cause this?

Even when I run the debug-version of KO, the error can not tell me what element it is referring to, which makes it hopeless to figure out where the error actually comes from.

I am also **not** using the second optional parameter when calling applybindings (no specific element target), as I am only doing this once anyway.

Comment: Do you *need* to update to the latest version?

Comment: Can't see anything related in the release notes (https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases/tag/v3.4.1) Are you sure you can't reproduce the issue in a simplified example? Could it be related to  a change in the `with` binding? https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/1415

Comment: Yes, please try to reproduce the error in a minimal example

Comment: If you use the debug version of Knockout, put a breakpoint in the code that throws the error (line 3247). Then you can use the debugger to see which element it is on and possibly the path it took to get there.

Comment: If this is caused by a bug in Knockout 3.4.1, it would great to track it down and get it fixed in the next version.

Comment: I also met this error but in Knockout 3.4.0. I am loading the script from https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.js. I have to comment the knockout binding code so that this error goes away. `//var vm = new ViewModel; ko.applyBindings(vm);`. The weird thing is this error does not always happen. It happened for a few days, then it suddenly went away. I added back the knockout binding code, then after few weeks, it comes back today. Ahhhh!

Comment: Another weird thing is the error happens in my production site. it does not happen when I test in localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

5 months after your question someone raised an issue with the same problem on their [Github page](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/2285). It was fixed [here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/commit/2606678f4f9a850aa959016f1c52738b9b11cc00).

Brian M Hunt's (one of the owners) comment:

> The issue was that the `valueAccessor()` needed to be called (if it's a function) to create the dependency. I believe I have the right fix for it in TKO (basically `if (typeof valueAccessor() === 'function') {valueAccessor()()}` in the render loop), but the TKO fix doesn't back-port/translate directly since it's using the new binding class style.